# Is it possible to export transparency effects from Blender to ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js, blender

I'm looking at this particular example http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/glass-91748.html

I have exported this glass into JSON with ThreeJS' exporter, but it does not show up with the material transparency achieved in blender upon render in the browser. In blender this glass effect is achieved with the via the Z-Transparency Alpha, Fresnel, and Blend settings. These settings are the magic sauce it seems. Without them in Blender, the glass appears as it does in the browser. While I might be able to correct this with a shader in Three.JS, I'm trying to determine if it is possible to do so without intervention.

ThreeJS 76
Blender 2.77

Comment: Plz, can you post versions (blender & three.js)

Comment: @TreizeCinq done, thanks.

Comment: did you get it to work

Comment: No, I did not, sorry.